# Общение несвязанных компонентов Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend

Доброго дня. Есть таблица где каждая ячейка представленна отдельным компонентом. Необходимо что бы при клике на любую ячейку всплывало небольшое меню, но при этом что бы при клике на другую ячейку открывалось новое меню, а это закрывалось. Я сам реализовал с помощью v-click-outside плагина. Но мне интересно что является гуд практикой, возможно общая шина событий ?

Comment: https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Коммуникация-между-компонентами-не-связанными-иерархически

Comment: На какую ячейку кликал?